# Flexbox column stretch on Childs height?

Tags: html, css, sass, flexbox

Im trying to build up a layout with flex box that needs to be dynamic to be used for certain use cases. I got a wrapper called `.app-content-inside` that uses 100% height of the viewport - the header and 100% of the viewport - the navigation bar on the left. This works fine so far.

```
.app-body-inner {
  padding: 0 !important;
  position: relative;
  width: inherit;
  height: calc(100vh - 40px); /* changed for demo */
  overflow: hidden;
 }
```

I use the class `.nrow-col` to add flex box column to certain `div`. If inside this div another one with the class `.nrow-row` exists this flexbox column child should be stretched to remaining vertical free space.

```
.nrow-col {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: inherit;
}

.nrow-col > .nrow-row {
  flex: auto;
}
```

To add flex box row I use the following class:

```
.nrow-row {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}
```

This works for the first instance but if I use HTML like this the inner flexbox column child is not stretched anymore:

```
<div class="app-body-inner">
  <div class="nrow-col">
    <div class="p-a top">
      topbar
    </div>
    <div class="row no-gutter nrow-row">
      <div class="col-sm-2">
        <div class="nrow-col">
          <div class="p-a top">
            coltop
          </div>
          <div class="nrow-row">
            <div class="nrow-body">
              <div class="nrow-inner">
                /\<br>
                this should stretch between coltop and colbottom<br>
                \/
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="p-a bottom">
            colbottom
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-10">
        <div class="nrow-col">
          <div class="p-a top">
            coltop
          </div>
          <div class="p-a top">
            coltop_another
          </div>
          <div class="row nrow-row">
            <div class="nrow-body">
              <div class="nrow-inner">
                /\<br>
                this should stretch between coltop_another and colbottom<br>
                \/
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="p-a bottom">
            colbottom
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="p-a bottom">
      bottombar
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

It is indeed very difficult to get my problem into text so I created a [plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/hQrxJTm9UR22U9a7NZPF?p=preview) that visualizes the problem I'm faced with...

Maybe somebody can help me

Comment: Is this what you want? Add `display: flex` to `.col-sm-2` and `.col-sm-10`. https://plnkr.co/edit/EsfplnxorYoINC13mO8x?p=preview

Comment: yes thats it !!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you make the nested parent containers into flex containers, they will automatically apply `align-items: stretch` to the children, causing them to consume all available height.

Here's what you need to add:

```
.col-sm-2, .col-sm-10 {
    display: flex;
}
```

[revised demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/EsfplnxorYoINC13mO8x?p=preview)

Comment: that works but if the content inside like in this plunks https://plnkr.co/edit/hQrxJTm9UR22U9a7NZPF?p=preview gets "long" how could I make the overflow to be hidden instead of overwriting the colbottom? the colbottom should stay on screen as well and the content of the `.row-body-inner` should be scrollable

Comment: `.row-body-inner` should be scrollable, `coltop` and `colbottom` should stay on screen

Comment: For `overflow: auto` to work, you'll need to define a height on the overflow element. Something like: coltop: 5%, colbottom: 5%, nrow: 90%; overflow: auto. Basically, for `overflow` to work you need to set a limit. Here's an example: https://plnkr.co/edit/OXZ70RnkaxumBYhYb5Km?p=preview

Comment: I got the needed behavior by adding `overflow-y: scroll` to `.nrow-row`

Comment: the last problem I'm facing is if I minimize the browser window to the smallest height possible ... the `colbottom` slides over the `coltop. Is there way of making `colbottom` not to overlap `coltop`but instead make the whole `.app-body-inner` scrollable. I therefore removed the `overflow:hidden;` from `.app-body-inner` ... updated plunkr here https://plnkr.co/edit/U6aov9pFqbHncnRxCxHT?p=preview ... how to get this to work?

Comment: You think there will be users who will *"minimize the browser window to the smallest height possible"*? In many layouts there are extreme situations where the layout breaks or just looks less-than-perfect. Investing time and money on these fixes may not be worth it, as the chances of that situation ever occurring in the real world are minimal.

Comment: But if the fix is important to you, then try giving the middle section a `min-height`, so the column never shrinks below a certain height. Or give coltop and/or colbottom some padding or margins, so there's a buffer of space between them.